# Loop at intersection of two objects (script)

Tags: mesh, scripting, modifiers

I'm looking for a Script or Add-on for Blender 2.79 that creates verts and a lines where two objects intersect.

### Practical example:

I need loops where the mountains intersect with the grass and where the grass intersects with the water for many purposes:

- Hitboxes around everything preventing player from leaving level (Extrude loops upward)
- AI boundaries where Ranged AI should not walk (Water)
- AI boundaries where Melee AI should not walk into / see player
- Boundaries for generating Vegetation using the Particle System

Image below is a part of the scene.

Some people recommended boolean and knife tools. It doesn't work out of the box, but I figured out a way and put it in a seperate answer below.

[image]

Comment: This is very similar to other question.

Comment: welder addon seems to work only for 2.8x. I didn't learn python or scripting for blender. Can't anyone just test/repair the existing script?

Comment: @vklidu Seriously the other answer has 31 upvotes and I used to work with the script. Why doesn't it work anymore? What's going on?

Comment: @vklidu I tried learning a bit of python and analyzing the script and yeah you're spot on. I just realised myself it's the wrong script. No idea where the right script went, I've looked online, my harddisk, back-ups, everywhere. Either I'll get lucky with the bounty here or I have to script this thing myself :\

Comment: @vklidu This question is an absolute mess already. Right now it's literally: "I've lost my script guys pls give me a new one"

Comment: @AzulShiva Thank you, great work on question. I just adjusted the title to something closer. You can change it back if you dont think so. Also you can delete comments here as well to let others to follow this page. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script of Witold Jaworski generates intersection of two selected meshes.

- Select two objects
- Press <kbd>W</kbd> (in 2.79), for 2.8x search *Intersection*
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> (Separate) > *Selected*

[image]
[image]
[image]

- [Version for 2.79](http://airplanes3d.net/downloads/scripts/25/object-intersection.zip)
- [Version for 2.8x](http://airplanes3d.net/downloads/scripts/28/object-intersection.zip)

For more detailed instructions [visit his site](http://airplanes3d.net/scripts-253_e.xml).

For future broken links – blend with script for version 2.79

[image]

For complex mesh like terrain is better select roughly vertices in intersected area to get script calcutlat faster, and I did quick cleaning of result (not perfect):

- in Edit mode select one of the longer edge than ussual
- search *Similar* > *Lenght* > *Greater*, Delete <kbd>X</kbd>
- than Select all and Search *Remove Doubles* (in 2.8x *Merge by Distance)*

(In tool properties you can increase minimum distance limit, it depence on how precise final intersection has to be. Higher value clean it better but in cost of preciseness (detail). Three gaps I had to connect manually. Pink line is the intersection object, converted into curve just to be visible in the image better.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is precisely what I am looking for. However I will leave the bounty open as there are some issues with it: 1) It's extremely slow (However it is possible to calculate the speed: Roughly 2 seconds for 1024x1024, 8 seconds for 2048x2048, 100 seconds for 50k x 1024, time will increase if the two objects's tri count deviates drastically) 2) Only works accurately with tris, so Ctr+T the mesh before Intersecting 3) It creates gaps and holes if two intersecting vertices are on the same spot. It can intersect two lines or two faces but not two verts.

Comment: If you preselect vertices in area of intersection, calculation is much faster. See blend.

Comment: If noone posts a better script the bounty goes to you. Thanks a lot. I also managed to get it working using standard boolean modifier, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

**Bmesh bisect plane.**

Here is a script that bisects one mesh with a plane and creates a new  mesh object with the intersecting edges.

[image]

In test example

- Grid is a 100 x 100 grid displaced with a cloud texture via a
  modifier (not applied).
- Plane is a single face default plane, named "Plane".
- Move plane to desired location and run script.
- New object "Bisect" has the edges of the bisection only.

[image]
*Still of result, since I hit stop on gif to quickly*

2.8 version

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
scene = context.scene 
ob = context.object
plane = scene.objects.get("Plane")

if plane and ob:
    pmw = plane.matrix_world
    face = plane.data.polygons[0]
    plane_co = pmw @ face.center
    plane_no = pmw @ (face.center + face.normal) - plane_co 
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_object(ob, dg)
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm,
            verts=bm.verts,
            matrix=ob.matrix_world)

    x = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm,
            geom=bm.faces[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.verts[:],
            clear_inner=True,
            clear_outer=True,
            plane_co=plane_co,
            plane_no=plane_no,
            )
    # new object
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Bisect")
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Bisect", me)
    context.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

2.7x version

[image]
*Result of running in 2.79 on modified grid, using a one face plane object named "Plane"*

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

scene = context.scene 
ob = context.object
plane = scene.objects.get("Plane")

if plane and ob:
    pmw = plane.matrix_world
    plane_co = pmw.translation
    face = plane.data.polygons[0]
    plane_no = pmw * (face.center + face.normal) - pmw * face.center 
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_object(ob, scene)
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm, verts=bm.verts, matrix=ob.matrix_world)
    x = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm,
            geom=bm.faces[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.verts[:],
            clear_inner=True,
            clear_outer=True,
            plane_co=plane_co,
            plane_no=plane_no,
            )
    # new object
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Bisect")
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Bisect", me)
    scene.objects.link(ob)
```

Comment: I get "Python script fail, look in the console for now..." Can you give precise info on which object to select? I'm using 2.79

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AzulShiva\Documents\Unity\Blender Files\blend_Levels\Level6.2_Terrain.blend\_Intersect.txt", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'evaluated_depsgraph_get'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

Comment: Clearly was for 2.8.  See edit for 2.7x

Comment: No error message this time, the script did something. Not what I wanted though: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/00c1a2-1580229796.jpg

Comment: I selected the hill mesh instead and I got this: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/4c7671-1580229878.jpg

Comment: @AzulShiva might have issue with transform space, will fix later it's late.

Comment: Sorry mate but your script seems to cut the active mesh along the x-y plain. I want two objects to intersect with each other. This is definitely not the desired result: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/7aa4e4-1580419801.jpg https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/2291ce-1580419924.jpg

Comment: "_Mate_"  I understand what the script does. Assumed the water object can be represented as a plane.  _"I need loops where the mountains intersect with the grass and where the grass intersects with the water for many purposes"_  then this is the logical way to do where the grass intersects with water part.   Have a nice proof of concept going akin to photoshop lasso projected (shrinkwrapped) back onto objects. (unfortunately it's for 2.8).

Comment: "I need loops where the mountains intersect with the grass" It's not possible to achieve this with your script.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder of **Bisect tool** in Blender 2.8x (as native tool) that can do similar kind of job (cut by plane).

- Duplicate your object
- Search Bisect
- Enable **Clear Inner** and **Clear Outer** in tool properties in left-down corner
- Adjust cut position (can be set numerically in properties too)

Done

[image]
For horizontal cut set Plane Normal values to 0/0/1 and move only Z axis of Plane Point parametr.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to cut by plane, I need to intersect two objects with each other. And I'm using 2.79

Comment: Sorry my fault, batFinger's script also works as a plane cut so I felt in mistake you are OK with that kind since I thought water surface is cutter. BTW 2.79 has the same tool I see.