# Intersection of objects taking into account plane scale

Tags: bmesh, bisect

After having a look at [Loop at intersection of two objects (script)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165198/loop-at-intersection-of-two-objects-script) was wondering if I could do intersection of plane with mesh taking into account the plane scale... If I use the bmesh as is I get the following...

[image]

How could I get only intersection within the plane taking ito account the scale, i.e not getting the wrists?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. What is the question? How to cut the mesh with the plane or howto make the script work as you describe?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! So my question is how to make the script work as I describe. i.e how to create the bisection affected by the area of the plane.

Additionaly it would be great if I could get to know how to detect those 3 group (figure and wrists) if discarding a whole plane cut is not an option...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did was to cast a ray, from that ray create a bisection with a flat plane, then I got the closest edge and vertex in the bisection from the ray hit position then explored the topology of the mesh getting only the vertices I could reach from that point:

```
# Perform bisection
        bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(
            bm,
            geom=bm.faces[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.verts[:],
            clear_inner=True,
            clear_outer=True,
            plane_co=plane_co,
            plane_no=plane_no
        )

        # Bisection cleanup
        closest_edge = self.find_closest_edge(bm)
        vertex_list = self.get_reachable_vertices(closest_edge)
        for v in [v for v in bm.verts if v not in vertex_list]:
            bm.verts.remove(v)
```

Example of exploring topology:

```
    def get_reachable_vertices(self, closest_edge):
    edge_list = [closest_edge]
    vertex_list = [v for v in closest_edge.verts]
    for v in vertex_list:
        for e in [edge for edge in v.link_edges if edge not in edge_list]:
            edge_list.append(e)
            if (e.other_vert(v) not in vertex_list):
                vertex_list.append(e.other_vert(v))

    return vertex_list
```